# Matrix Factorization and Linear Regression

Tags: regression, scikit-learn, matrix-decomposition

Which matrix factorization algorithm is used in LinearRegression() function of scikit-learn?

Answer (score 1):

The singular value decomposition, by default. The documentation says it uses `scipy.linalg.lstsq`, and the documentation for that [says](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lstsq.html) the default is Lapack's `gelsd`, and the documentation for *that* [says](https://scc.ustc.edu.cn/zlsc/sugon/intel/mkl/mkl_manual/GUID-EC167C45-1A4E-4D3C-8652-9B48C788CDF0.htm)

> Computes the minimum-norm solution to a linear least squares problem
> using the singular value decomposition of A and a divide and conquer
> method.

That is, it does most of a singular value decomposition to get $U^TBV$ where $B$ is bidiagonal, and then solves the linear system from there.

Other options provided are SVD without any additional cleverness, and a complete orthogonal factorisation (which reduces to a QR decomposition if the design matrix has full rank)